# Is a codimension one closed subgroup of a connected linear algebraic group is automatically normal?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group and let $H$ be a closed subgroup of $G$ of codimension one. Is $H$ necessarily normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Try taking a look at the [$ax+b$ group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10859/matrix-representation-of-axb-group) -- a.k.a. the group of one-dimensional affine linear transformations -- over your favorite field, for instance.